# Prism and Unity - prevent auto creation of type

Tags: unity-container, prism

I'm creating a WPF app using Prism and Unity as the container. A couple of times I've come unstuck with the order of registering types whereby a type (ViewModel into View constructor) has been auto created by Unity when I've not registered it. Then I've tried to register the type using ContainerControlledLifetimeManager() and **thought** I'd created a singleton. However the auto creation has meant multiple instances of the view model.

Besides the obvious solution of not being a muppet and not doing the above, is there a way to prevent Unity auto creating unregistered types and perhaps throwing an exception instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define an interface for each of your ViewModels and then register them accordingly.

```
public interface IViewModel
{
     List<IUser> Users { get; }
}

public class ViewModel : IViewModel
{
     List<IUser> Users { get; }
}

Container.RegisterType<IViewModel, ViewModel>();
```

In your constructor make sure that the interface type is being injected, not the concrete type as Unity will certainly construct an instance of a concrete type since it is resolvable; whereas an interface can have N implementations.

In addition, your code should be constructed in that the data that needs to exist across the application should come form a service, not the ViewModel. Making your ViewModel a singleton should not be your approach, proxy the data through a service. this way your ViewModel can be constructed/destroyed at will, the data you want persisted exists elsewhere.

```
Container.RegisterType<IService, Service>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
Container.RegisterType<IViewModel, ViewModel>();

...

public List<IUser> Users
{
     get { return Container.Resolve<IService>().GetUsers(); }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift response. I generally haven't bothered creating interfaces for viewmodels as I couldn't see the point as they are tied to the views they provide the data context for. I've seen some pros and cons for this but for me its overkill. Perhaps I need to rethink this. So there is no configuration option?

Comment: If you register a given type; it defaults to a transient lifetime. Using the `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager` will certainly provide singleton behavior, however you do not _typically_ want to do that with a ViewModel. Keep in mind that ViewModel can be used across multiple Views. In addition it allows you to swap out the concrete type for testing or other means in a fairly trivial way. Unity creating the instance of the concrete type is non-configurable that I am aware of, it's the behavior of the container. The singleton example should work, would need code to understand your example.

Comment: Container.Resolve<T>() is a horrible practice! 
Proxying data through a service is excellent advice!